# Where is the Component Initialize Method in Asp.NET 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create my own naming convention for page events rather than AutoEventWireUp but I couldn't find Component Initialize methods any where ? Should I override it ? But in which class it is defined ?

Thanks...

**Edit :**

For example : I don't want to use `Page_Load` but `LoadThisPage` naming. So It should be like

```
Load += new LoadThisPage(sender,e);
```

I was expecting a `InitializeComponent` method where I can initialize page,controls etc. events handlers...But it turned out to be `Constructor` function :)

So what confused me is I thought there should have been a method like `InitializeComponent` which does things for me already created by Designer itself so I thought I could define my own event handler names within this method by overriding it in the say `Default.aspx.cs` .

But the answer was simple :) Thanks...

Comment: I answered this, but feel like I answered the wrong thing, can you give an example of what you want the code to look like when you have made your changes to the environment?

Comment: What do you mean "should I override it"?  Override what?  The Page constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't really clear as to what you're trying to do.

Page events are defined in the `System.Web.UI.Page` class, some of which are inherited from `System.Web.UI.Control`.   You don't need to use AutoEventWireUp if you don't want to, and you're free to override all of the Page methods that would normally raise the lifecycle events (`OnInit`, `OnLoad`, `OnPreRender`, etc.) and then *not* call the base methods, effectively squelching the events from being raised.

You can see some limited discussion around this [on this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2008/03/24/onload-vs-page-load-vs-load-event.aspx).

As Hogan noted, this sounds like a bad idea.  Could you expand on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is actually what I really want. Thanks.

Comment: hmmm... that link says nothing about component-initialize **shrug**

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bad idea to me.

However, you should be able to find auto-created code by selecting the project display options, I believe it is right click in project explorer, and selecting display hidden files or display all files.  Then you will see additional .vb files created by the system.  You might also have click on the little plus sign.

**additonal added notes**

Most of the events (btw) are defined in the base class(es) in System.Web.UI.Page and not in the code created for a specific instance.